# Fallo al extender layouts.app

Tags: laravel-5

En el fichero app.blade.php tengo el siguiente código dentro de la etiqueta "body":

```
style="background-image: url('fondos/fondo.jpg')"
```

Esto se heredara en otras vistas y hara que todas las vistas tengan esta imagen, como en esta:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div align="center"  class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1 style="color:#9999FF;" class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Jardin botánico Floramania") }} </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Logged()
            @Hueco()
            <a href="formulario/rol">Elegir rol</a>
            @endHueco
            <a class="pull-left" href="souvenirs">
                @Cliente()
                Tienda Online
                @endCliente
                @Administrador()
                Lista de Souvenirs
                @endAdministrador
            </a>
            @Cliente()
            <a class="pull-right" href="formulario/saldo">Realizar un ingreso</a>
            @if(is_null(Auth::user()->saldo)==false)
            <h4 style="color:#55AADD" class="pull-center">Saldo actual: {{Auth::user()->saldo}}€</h4><br>
            <a class="pull-left" href="entrada/{{Auth::user()->id}}">Ver tus entradas</a>

            <r class="pull-center">
                @if(Auth::user()->saldo>=7)
                <a href="formulario/entrada">Comprar entrada (7€)</a>
                @else
                <i style="color:#0000FF">Necesitas 7€ para comprar una entrada</i>
                @endif
            </r>
            @endif
            @endCliente
            @Administrador()
            <a class="pull-right" href="entrada">Lista de entradas</a><br><br>
            <a class="pull-left" href="formulario/plantas">Crear una nueva planta</a>
            @endAdministrador
            @Legal()
            @if(Auth::user()->rol=='administrador' || is_null(Auth::user()->saldo)==false)
            <a href="clientela" class="pull-right">Lista de usuarios</a>
            @endif
            @endLegal
            @include('partials.errors')
            @else
            <p style="color:#0000FF">Inicia sesión para realizar operaciones</p>
            @endLogged
        </div>
    </div>
    @forelse($planta as $plantas)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3>
                <a href="comentarios/{{ $plantas->id }}">{{ $plantas->nombre }}</a>
                @Administrador()
                <a href="borrar/{{ $plantas->id }}" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Eliminar planta</a>
                <a href="modificar/{{ $plantas->id }}" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Modificar planta</a>
                @endAdministrador
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h4>{{ $plantas->descripcion }}</h4>
            @if($plantas->foto)
            <img src="{{ $plantas->rutas() }}" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid green" class="img-responsive img-rounded" />
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <b>Tamaño:</b> {{ $plantas->tamaño }}<br>
            <b>Flor:</b> {{ $plantas->flor }}<br>
            <b>Hoja:</b> {{ $plantas->hoja }}<br>
            <span class="pull-right"> {{ __("Comentarios") }}: {{ $plantas->comentarios->count() }} </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    @empty
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ __("No hay ninguna planta en este momento") }}
    </div>
    @endforelse
</div>
@endsection
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, me encuentro con que no siempre es así, como en este ejemplo:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div align="center" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-heading">
            <h2 style="color:#0088FF;" class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Comentarios acerca del :nombre", ['nombre' => $plantas->nombre]) }} </h2>
        </div>
        @forelse($comentario as $c)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-forum">
                <h3>
                    Escrito por {{$c->usuario->name}}
                    @Logged()
                        @if(Auth::user()->id==$c->usuario->id && $c->comentario!="Comentario Eliminado")
                            <a href="../cambiar/{{ $c->id }}" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Borrar el comentario</a>
                        @endif
                    @endLogged
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ $c->comentario }}
            </div>
        </div>
        @empty
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ __("No hay ningún comentario sobre esta planta actualmente") }}
        </div>
        @endforelse

        @Logged()
        @include('partials.errors')
        <form method="POST" action="../comentario">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="planta" value="{{ $plantas->id }}"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comentario" class="col-md-12 control-label"> {{ __("Escribe un comentario...") }}
                </label>
                <input id="comentario" class="form-control" name="comentario" value="{{ old('comentario') }}"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="addComentario" class="btn btn-default"> {{ __("Añadir Comentario") }}
            </button>
        </form>
        @else
        <h6 style="color:#0000FF;" class="text-center text-mute">(Tienes que iniciar sesión si quieres escribir comentarios)</h6>
        @endLogged

    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que estare haciendo mal en el segundo caso?

Más información. He probado a poner dentro del head de app.blade.php el siguiente código:

```
@stack('styles')
```

Una vez hecho esto, he modificado mis dos ejemplos para que tengan solamente este código:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@push('styles')
    <body style="background-image: url('fondos/fondo.jpg');"/>
@endpush
@endsection
```

Para mi sorpresa, a pesar de que el código es exactamente igual en ambos casos, sigue apareciendo mi imagen en el primer ejemplo, pero en el segundo no.

Ambas vistas las tengo ubicadas en \resources\views\vegetal. La primera es ***index.blade*** y la seguna ***detail.blade***.

Comment: Por cierto, he notado que encima esto funciona de forma distinta segun si estoy usando el PC de casa o un portatil. En el PC de casa no se ve ninguna imagen, pero en mi portatil si que se ven.

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco he tenido un caso similar, en el que he necesitado aplicar ciertos estilos en algunos layouts, mi solución fue añadir en el layout principal un `@stack('#')`, en tu caso ´layouts.app´. Esto permite que puedas cargar un estilo diferente en cada layout

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="{{ asset('css/base.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >

@stack('styles')
```

Hecho esto, desde cada layout cargo los estilos correspondientes.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @push('styles')
        <link href="{{ asset('css/style_background.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    @endpush
    <codigo layout>
@stop
```

Comment: Lo he probado, pero sigo en las mismas. En el primer ejemplo lo que sugieres funciona, pero sigue sin mostrarse el fondo en la segunda vista.

Comment: De hecho, he añadido más información.

Comment: No se si actualmente lo usas, pero a mi me ayuda mucho el "debug bar" yo uso este https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: Puedes revisar si en el inspector de chrome `F12` sale algún error de porque no encuentra la imagen? Quizás la ruta no sea correcta en el segundo caso ya que la URL de la página es diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no entiendo lo que pretendes hacer, estás complicando una situación extremadamente sencilla con unas muy malas prácticas tanto de Laravel como de uso de estilos:

1. Utilizar estilos 'inline' en general es una mala práctica y más en contextos de templates de Laravel, donde se juega tanto con incluir templates y variables dentro de otros templates. Los estilos deberían estar en un archivo externo (.css) y listo, utilizar clases para acceder a la información que se necesita para cada elemento o página, hay que tener en cuenta que las direcciones en CSS son relativas, por lo cual es importante saber como escribir las rutas.

   ```
   body {
     background-image: url('https://miurl.com/fondos/fondo.jpg');
   }
   ```
2. La directiva `@stack` de Blade está diseñada para "acumular" elementos, pueden ser clases, contenedores, referencias a archivos externos, pero NUNCA la etiqueta body. Es muy riesgosa esta práctica, y se perdería la estructura y coherencia del layout fácilmente, además no me imagino teniendo que definir el body en cada template de Blade. No es práctico desde ningún punto de vista.

En vez de hacer esto:

```
@stack('styles')

@push('styles')
    <body style="background-image: url('fondos/fondo.jpg');"/>
@endpush
```

Yo haría algo así (sin cerrar la etiqueta con / al final de la misma):

```
// template principal
<body class="@stack('body-class')">

// en cada template que lo necesite (pero si se necesita en todos, se pone en el template principal
@push('body-class') basic-page @endpush


// en el archivo de css
.basic-page {
  background-image: url('https://miurl.com/fondos/fondo.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre que ambas vistas tengan fondo.
Para eso puse este código en app.css, en public/css:

```
body{
    background-image: url('../fondos/fondo.jpg');
}
```

El url tomaba base en public/css cuando lo que yo busco estaba en public/fondos, por lo que he tenido que dar "un paso atras" para solucionarlo.